# How to pass data between unrelated ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift

I'm building a simple movie app by fetching some data from an API.   My app navigation pattern looks like this:  NavigationController as InitialViewController > TabBarController. TabBarController includes two ViewControllers: HomeViewController and FavouriteMoviesViewController. I have a button inside HomeViewController which pushes the SeachViewController page using navigation. I also have DetailsViewController. Whenever I press movie poster whether in HomeViewController or SearchViewController CollectionViewCell, it presents me DetailsPageViewController. I'm using delegation pattern(i set FavouriteMoviesViewController as a delegate of the DetailsViewController when I present DetailsViewController from HomeViewController) to update data inside FavouriteMoviesViewController from DetailsViewController, but the problem is that I can't set delegate when I access DetailsViewController from SearchViewController because these two ViewControllers are not related in any way. I tried to set an observer inside FavouriresViewController, but it won't work until I access that viewController

here's my code when i present DetailsViewController from HomeViewController and pass fetched data

```
// Cell action
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // Instantiate DetailsViewController and set it's delegate to FavouritesViewController to pass data
    let targetVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: DetailsViewController.identifier) as! DetailsViewController
    let favMoviesScreen = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers?[0] as! FavouritesViewController
    targetVC.changeToFavouriteDelegate = favMoviesScreen

    switch collectionView {
    case self.trendingMoviesCollectionView:
        let selectedMovie = trendingMovies[indexPath.row]
        targetVC.movie = selectedMovie
        targetVC.genreIDs = selectedMovie.genreIDs
        self.navigationController?.present(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case self.upcomingMoviesCollectionView:
        let selectedMovie = upcomingMovies[indexPath.row]
        targetVC.movie = selectedMovie
        targetVC.genreIDs = selectedMovie.genreIDs
        self.navigationController?.present(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    case self.topRatedMoviesCollectionView:
        let selectedMovie = topRatedMovies[indexPath.row]
        targetVC.movie = selectedMovie
        targetVC.genreIDs = selectedMovie.genreIDs
        self.navigationController?.present(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    default: break
    }
    
}
```

everything's good here.

here's DetailsViewController where i show movie details, i mark favourite movie here and add/remove it in my FavouriteMoviesViewController, this is delegate method:

```
// MARK: - Button Actions

@objc private func markAsFavourite() {

    guard let favouriteMovie = movie else {
        print("invalid movie object")
        return
    }
    // check whether the movie is already added into favourite movies array
    if !DetailsViewController.favouriteMovies.contains(where: { favouriteMovie.movieId == $0.movieId }) {
        addToFavouritesButton.tintColor = .appRedColor
        DetailsViewController.favouriteMovies.append(favouriteMovie)
        changeToFavouriteDelegate?.addMovie(favouriteMovie)
    } else {
        addToFavouritesButton.tintColor = .white
        DetailsViewController.favouriteMovies.removeAll(where: { $0.movieId == favouriteMovie.movieId})
        changeToFavouriteDelegate?.removeMovie(favouriteMovie)
    }
   
}
```

now the problem is here, in my SearchViewController,i guess because of the fact that this ViewController doesnt' belong to tabBar

```
// Cell action
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let targetVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: DetailsViewController.identifier) as! DetailsViewController
    let tabBar = (self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0]) as! UITabBarController
    let favMoviesController = tabBar.viewControllers![0] as! FavouritesViewController
    targetVC.changeToFavouriteDelegate = favMoviesController
    let selectedMovie = filteredMovies[indexPath.row]
    targetVC.movie = selectedMovie
    targetVC.genreIDs = selectedMovie.genreIDs
    self.navigationController?.present(targetVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

this just doesn't work...

targetVC.changeToFavouriteDelegate = favMoviesController

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: In general, it's better to move shared data out of view controllers.  Passing it between them is convenient but you've arrived at a level of complexity where app data should be responsible for itself.  There are lots of Google sources for MVC or MVVM patterns.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer. I had doubts that the problem was with data placement, but at the same time, I was feeling that I was missing something in the delegation, notification patterns.
I guess it's time to learn how real men code, using the MVVM pattern. thanks again, Philipps, I appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not answer your question completely however my intention is to point you in the right direction.

The issue could be one of several and it will be hard to debug without being able to run your code. Here are some possibilities:

1. Your delegate could be set correctly but because the Favorites View is not on the screen, the UI updates are not executed and you do not do any reloading / refreshing when you go back there
2. Maybe you are not accessing the desired instance of the Favorites ViewController
3. One reason notifications would have not worked, maybe you aren't listening to it
4. etc

It's hard to say easily.

In my opinion, the implementation to achieve what you want is quite complex.

I would recommend to simplify in the following ways:

1. Simplest solution - Maintain a [struct or a class](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html) of favorite movies which should be passed around between the classes
2. One step further would be to look at MVVM as one of the commenters posted and using that with observers (Notifications) to update UI. I recommend [checking this stanford lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--qKOhdgJAs&ab_channel=Stanford) which I liked
3. Might be an overkill at this stage but can read up on [CoreData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata) to see if it suits your needs

Comment: Edit: With pure luck, i managed to solve the problem. turns out that button didn't respond when I was using presentViewController, but when I'm using pushViewController everything works perfectly.

Anyways thanks for your answer, much appreciated. I'll dig into  the material that you provided, looks interesting

Comment: @Sevenfortyseven - that's a great find ! Do you already know the difference between pushing and using present ? If not, check out push / show vs present in terms of navigation hierarchy !

Comment: I thought I knew, boy i was wrong, haha, guess I'm learning a hard way:)